# Tyring to install civicrm-5.15.1 on Joomla 3.9.9 Stable - "Installation error com_civicrm/admin/configure.php on line 115"

Tags: joomla, error, installation

sorry for my approximate English.

civicrm-5.15.1-joomla

Joomla! 3.9.9 Stable

Unfortunately the installation ends with the following error message.

```
Fatal error : require_once(): Failed opening required '/membri/testastuta/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.settings.php' (include_path='.:') in /membri/testastuta/tmp/install_5d2c80922fb4c/com_civicrm/admin/configure.php on line 115
```

Comment: This seems very similar to https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/21899/tyring-to-upgrade-to-civicrm-4-7-28-on-joomla-but-wsod-error-says-civicrm-settin. Do the comments at the bottom there help?